# Retrieving file name while it's being downloaded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

For reasons i'm not going to get into i need to get the name of the file that is being downloaded in the instance of that browser.
Is there a way using selenium to get the name of the file being downloaded? Not talking about waiting for it to download and get the name after

I am using selenium with chrome and python.

Comment: Name of file is the last section of URL.

Comment: the url does not change when i download, no name appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i ended up going in another direction with this, i am simply creating folders for each browser instance i open and each instance only downloads in that folder and retrieve the name from there.